# componentDidUpadate Infinite loop with auth0 isAuthenticated

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I need to wait user data from auth0 api, to setState.
I try to do this with componentDidUpdate, but i have an infinite loop
What's wrong in this code ? :

```
    class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { user } = this.props.auth0;


    // Context state
    this.state = {
      races: {},
      regions: {},
      allAnnonces: {},
      profile: {}
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.props.auth0.user;
 console.log("componentDidMount",this.props.auth0.isAuthenticated);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const isAuthenticated = this.props.auth0.isAuthenticated;

    if (prevProps.isAuthenticated != isAuthenticated) {
      this.setState({ userInfos: "test" });
    }
  }


  render() {
  if (isLoading) {
      return <Loading />;
    }

    return (
     <>hello</>
    )
   }
```

Here the Auth0 props :

[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (prevProps.auth0 != isAuthenticated)`?

Comment: Ok, what I'm gonna ask may sound stupid normally, but we have to make sure anyway: even though *isAuthenticated* is descriptive (indicating it's a *boolean* or *number*), can you confirm to me it is not an *object*? And post the *auth0* object, just for courtesy.

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe mean

`const isAuthenticated = this.props.auth0.isAuthenticated;` ?

Comment: yes it's that, i corrected but is still the same problem

Comment: @cecilecemoi post the code for the whole component

Comment: ok i posted the whole component